# How to get participant id for google play game?

Tags: android, google-play-services

It's very easy to get the participant Ids for a **realtime** game. Just make a room and get them from this callback...

```
@Override
    public void onPeerJoined(Room room, List<String> participantIds) {
        System.out.println(participantIds.get(0) + participantIds.get(1));
    }
```

However, how can I get the participantIds for a **turnbasedmultiplayer** game?

Comment: have you tried using a `Log.i` instead of `System.out.println`?

Comment: @gian1200 I'm not trying to print it to console I want the actual value

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, and if `List<String> participantIds` returns a list of IDs; then, you can do something like:

```
@Override
public void onPeerJoined(Room room, List<String> participantIds) {
    for (String id : participantIds) {
        Log.i("ASDF", "This is an ID: " + id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[Link](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/games/multiplayer/turnbased/TurnBasedMatch.html#getParticipantIds%28%29)

```
    public abstract ArrayList<String> getParticipantIds()
```

Returns the IDs of the participants in this match. These are returned in the participant order of the match. Note that these are not stable across matches.